# Notification when any property changes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

In OSX,

Suppose I have a Foo that has some Bar's and in a xib i have an array controller hooked to Foo's list of Bars and in the xib there are controls (say a textfield) bound to the Bar's properties. How can I get notified in Foo that one of the Bars property has changed.

I know i could add an observer for every property on each Bar but that seems like way to much book keeping especially if any property changes. I'd like to know when any property changes without having to enumerate all of them in code.

I know I could also use `NSNotificationCenter` but then i'd have to override each Bar's `-(void)set...` and add in posting the notification.

My question is if there is an easier way to get notified of all property changes of an object without tons of boiler plate code.